# how to use variable name with image tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my controller uses code like this:

```
if  params[:commit] == "Submit"
```

this used to work fine when I just had buttons. however, now I am using images as buttons like below:

```
<%= image_submit_tag 'butons/Add-08.png',  :class => 'image-button-submit' %>
```

How can I pass the `commit` variable with value `Submit` along with this `image_submit_tag`?

Answer (score 2):

KandadaBoggu is right, but that will (in most browsers) give you a `params['commit.x']` and `params['commit.y']` rather than just `params['commit']`.

If there's only the one button on the form (and you're posting to the same action that renders the form) you can do `if request.post?` instead, but that's only going to work if there's just one button, ie: only submit, not submit and cancel.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [image_submit_tag documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M001740) you can pass any HTML options. I haven't tested this but the following code should work.

```
<%= image_submit_tag 'butons/Add-08.png', :name =>"commit", :value =>"Submit" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try passing it as a hidden field inside of the form you're submitting.

```
hidden_field_tag "commit", "Submit"
```